# Redes Neurais Convolucionais Tensorflow

Tags: python, redes-neurais, tensorflow

Olá, pessoal!!
Estou com um problema acredito que seja no meu conjunto de treinamento. tenho um numpy array com imagens 649 imagens para treinamento de minha rede no entanto ao iniciar o treinamento(model.fit) vejo que apenas 21 imagens estão "chegando" para esse treinamento. Alguém saberia me informar o que poderia estar acontecendo?

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=[100, 100, 3]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="Adam", metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=25)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `.fit()` tem como padrão um `batch_size=32`. Isso significa que, para uma atualização dos pesos (backpropagation), serão utilizadas 32 imagens por vez. Como seu dataset tem 649 imagens, serão realziados 21 backpropagations por época. (`649/32 = 20.3`)

Se quiser que sejam realizados 649 backpropagations por época, utilize `batch_size=1`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Alex! este é meu primeiro projeto na área de IA. Estou passando por alguns sufocos haha!